# Changing header text from uppercase to normal

Tags: headers

All header text is uppercase.

In main-style.css this works:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin:0;
    text-transform:none;
}
```

but, when I do any changes in Appearance > Customize or in Cherry Options it overrides the changes above.
Also, adding the above code to style.css doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is the text uppercase or lowercase in the page source?

Comment: What is the class or id of its?

Comment: Do not use the word Wordpress to make your question specific to wordpress. Simply adding that does not make your question on topic. This is CSS which is better suited for stackoverflow.com

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try adding the !important tag

```
text-transform:none!important;
```

Comment: Thank you! '!important' worked. I added it into the main-style.css